# Google Cloud Storage request blocked by CORS: not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

#### What am I trying to accomplish?

I am trying to make a direct file upload to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I'm successfully creating a **direct upload link** via my Ruby on Rails API ActiveStorage setup.

Using the created direct upload link, I am trying to make a `PUT` request to my Google Cloud Storage bucket in my frontend client (Next.js).

#### What issue am I encountering?

In my frontend client, I'm making a `PUT` request with `fetch` and receiving the following **CORS error**:

In Chrome:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://storage.googleapis.com//?GoogleAccessId=<ACCESS_ID>&Expires=1678985734&Signature=' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

In Safari:

> Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200
> Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200

#### Code Details

As per [Google Cloud's CORS configuration](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cors-configurations), this is the CORS policy for my storage bucket:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["http://localhost:8080"],
    "method": ["GET", "PUT"],
    "responseHeader": ["Origin", "Content-Type", "Content-MD5", "Content-Disposition"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

I have confirmed this CORS configuration is present by running:
`gcloud storage buckets describe gs://<BUCKET_NAME> --format="default(cors)"`

My direct upload fetch in my frontend client is pretty simple:

```
const directUpload = async (directUpload: DirectUpload) => {
  const response = await fetch(directUpload.url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: JSON.parse(directUpload.headers),
    body: file,
  });

  return response;
}
```

The request headers for `PUT` (from the network tab) are as follows:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="logo.png"; filename*=UTF-8''logo.png
Content-Type: image/png
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6 Safari/605.1.15
Content-MD5: y+5qHSqBo9Kmlkln9P0vAQ==
```

The response headers from GCS from the `PUT` request (Status code 403):

```
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
content-length: 363
content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 20 Mar 2023 16:39:30 GMT
server: UploadServer
x-guploader-uploadid: <UPLOAD_ID>
```

The **request headers** of the **preflight** request:

```
:authority: storage.googleapis.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: <DIRECT_UPLOAD_PATH>
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
access-control-request-headers: content-disposition,content-md5,content-type
access-control-request-method: PUT
cache-control: no-cache
origin: http://localhost:8080
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://localhost:8080/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

The **response headers** from GCS of the **preflight** request:

```
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,Content-MD5,Content-Disposition
access-control-allow-methods: GET,PUT
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
access-control-max-age: 3600
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 16 Mar 2023 19:26:23 GMT
expires: Thu, 16 Mar 2023 19:26:23 GMT
server: UploadServer
vary: Origin
x-guploader-uploadid: <UPLOAD_ID>
```

I can see that the `Origin` header *should match* the **origin** setup in my bucket CORS policy.

#### Attempted Solutions

I have seen numerous other posts with similar CORS errors of **not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**. From these posts I have experimented with:

- Changing `"origin": ["http://localhost:8080"]` to `"origin": ["*"]` in the CORS policy for my storage bucket
- Using a `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch` in my frontend code
- Checking the [Troubleshoot CORS requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-cors#troubleshooting) suggestions

Comment: What's in `directUpload.headers`? You'll likely need to explicitly allow those request headers in your CORS config.

Comment: @jub0bs `Content-MD5` and `Content-Disposition` are in `directUpload.headers`. I added these to my bucket's CORS policy's `responseHeader`: ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type", "Content-MD5", "Content-Disposition"]

Unfortunately, the same issue persists.

Comment: Unlikely to be the cause of your issue, but `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` needs not be listed there.

Comment: Check the preflight request in your browser's Network tab. It contains a header named `Access-Control-Request-Headers`. The header names listed in it must be allowed by your CORS config for preflight to succeed. One or more header names are likely missing there. Good luck!

Comment: I added the request and response headers of the preflight request to my main post. `Access-Control-Request-Headers` appears to match `allow-headers` in the response. Thank you for pointing out the preflight request, it has improved the details of the question!

Comment: I must be missing something... Based on the details you've added to your question, preflight should succeed. I don't know...

Comment: Can you also share the _response_ headers of the PUT request?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thanks for taking a look! I have edited the post to include the response headers of the `PUT` request to GCS.

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing on the PUT response itself, it is only present on the preflight response. That explains the observed behavior, although I cannot explain why the header is missing on the PUT response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully make the `PUT` direct upload request to Google Cloud Storage after making a change found in this write up: https://finnian.io/blog/uploading-files-to-s3-react-native-ruby-on-rails

> Finally I was able to make it work by forcing Active Storage to use v4
> of the GCS presigned post URL. You can achieve this by setting the
> cache_control property of your service in storage.yml. I’m not sure
> why this setup doesn’t seem to work with v2, but there you go. Maybe
> it’ll help you.

This involved adding `cache_control: "public, max-age=3600"` to my `google` service in `storage.yml` as per active storage guide here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#google-cloud-storage-service

I also added `"Cache-Control"` to the `responseHeader` list uploaded to my GCS bucket CORS policy.

This resulted in the successful `PUT` request to GCS which uploaded the file to my bucket.

Adding `cache_control` in Rails forces using `v4` (instead of `v2`) for generating signed URLs. More information on the signing URLs can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#types

> • V4 signing with service account authentication: This signing mechanism is described below.
>
> • V2 signing with service account authentication: This is a legacy mechanism for creating signed URLs, and its usage is not recommended.

Comment: Note: adding `"Cache-Control"` to the CORs policy is *not optional* if you set `cache_control: [...]` in storage.yml

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and cookies:

Browser caches can cause issues when changes are made to CORS policies. Clear your browser cache and cookies to ensure that you're working with the most recent CORS configuration.

Comment: Good call out. Unfortunately, I have tried in an incognito window with the same results.

Answer (score -4):

I resolved the issue by installing the cors node module and adding this on the requested server

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```